# How to create buttons in the form of gridview in android studio

Tags: android, button, gridview

Actually i had already posted this question but it was on hold .Well i am creating an android app which comprises of a grid view form in the Homescreen page. However i want my grid view in form of buttons that will lead to different activities.Can anyone suggest me how to do it? here is a sample of what i am trying to do:
[Homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcXIG.jpg)

Comment: Yes you can use the GridView with custom adapter

Comment: can i get the codes please?? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [GridView (link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and add your Items to it's Adapter. EDIT: The elements in this grid are then clickable and you just have to react to the clicks. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) you can find an example of how [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) is used.